# Parallax Websites & SEO

Tags: seo, web-development, search-engines, google-search, ecommerce

I am getting a parallax website made for my e-commerce website. I have the option of giving each section an individual link or anchor tagging each page.

Which of the two options are better for SEO? I would prefer to anchor tag each page so people can return to their previous page without hitting the back button several times.

Comment: By "anchor tagging", do you mean putting all the content into one page and deep linking to it with a `#` in the URL, thus allowing users to scroll to see all the content?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question is you are building a one page parallax type site but you want the navigation sections to modify the urls so you break them down for seo purposes?  For example you have a one page template page.html and then there are other urls created from clicking the nagigation links?

If i am correct in my assumption, you really have two questions.  First is the Back button and second is SEO.

In regards to the back button, anytime you change the url then you are really looking at dealing with the back button and browser history.   If you use hashes (anchors) the benefit is that your user will be taken to the proper section of the page if they visit the url with the hash.  If you are using full urls then you have to code in some Javascript routing and browser pushstate to support this (this means older browsers which dont support pushstate will fail).

For SEO:

If you go with the hashbang route, (anchorts) then you neeed to tell google spider how to parse only the hash content .  You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started
Eseentially you are mapping the hashed page to one that only shows google the content for the specific slide.

If you are going with HTML Pushstate then you have to support the full urls if they are reuested by google spider.

In my opinion using Hashbang is the cleaner and easier approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with your preference of moving with anchor text and I would suggest you to have a simple navigation and the best would be with mouse over all inner page and section should be open in chart forum so that user should get every thing about the inner page at once glance.